# Many frame in java - trying to open a new window when I click on a button

Tags: java, swing, frame

I'm trying to open a new window when I click on a button. In this new window there is a form. The form contains information which is used to create a JScrollPane in the first window. I'd like to create the JScrollPane when the user completes all the element in the form. I tried with Thread but this does not work.

This is my code :

```
f(e.getSource() == menuAjoutern){
        JScrollPane scrollpane;
        nomniveaux++;

        Frame p = new Frame();
        p.setContentPane(new PanelInfoCrea());
        p.setVisible(true);

        /*Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Frame p = new Frame();
                p.setContentPane(new PanelInfoCrea());
                p.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        t.start();


        Frame.creation = true;
        while(Frame.creation) {
            try {
                System.out.println("oui");
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(Frame.p.getListeNiveau().get(Frame.p.getListeNiveau().size()-1).dessinerPlateauCreation(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), hauteur));
        pane.add("niveau "+nomniveaux ,scrollpane);
    }
```

Here I try to wait that boolean is false for create the JScrollPane. The boolean change state when second window is close.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: [Some similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+wait+for+jframe+to+close&*). I also posted a community wiki answer before I found the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd window should be a modal JDialog or a JOptionPane (which actually is a modal dialog). This way the calling code will halt when the 2nd window has been displayed and won't resume until the 2nd window is no longer visible.

Comment: JDialog works, thanks !